# How can I delete soft/motherboard RAID 1 from a different computer?

Tags: partitioning, raid, software-raid, raid-1

I have a drive.  It was part of a RAID 1 mirror on a motherboard-based raid controller (nVidia controller on an ASUS A8N-SLI Deluxe), which, if I understand correctly, is considered to be "soft" raid, even though it's independent of the OS.  Both of the SATA controllers on that motherboard are having issues, which means it doesn't recognize that the disk is still in an array.  I've since dismantled that computer and moved the drive to a new one.  I want to repartition the drive, so I booted into gparted and kicked off a resize/move of the larger partition and then growth of the smaller one.  It failed partway through, alerting me that it was having trouble due to the fact that the dmraid driver wasn't loaded and the disk was now a mess (it deleted the first partition and resized the second, but now both appear empty).  It wasn't until then that I realized I was working on the RAID partitions.  I then switched to /dev/sda and found the "real" partitions, at which point I cursed a few times, and then came here.

So my question is this: if I don't care about saving the data at this point, how do I "reset" the disk back to a standard disk, given that it's in a different computer with a completely different SATA controller (now AMD from the ASUS M5A97 LE R2.0 motherboard)?  Can I do this from gparted, or a Gentoo LiveCD (the two live environments I already have discs burned for)? Should I just start the Windows 7 installation at this point, and hope it allows me to wipe it out?

Comment: Well, possibly good news on the data front...a reboot into a fresh gparted environment now shows the new partition size, a fairly full partition, and the partition label on /dev/sda. Still shows the virtual disk though.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was simple.   Booted Gentoo,  and `dmraid -rE` did the trick.

Comment: @Karan Whoops, read it on the review and it read weird. Now I see it